# How to implement active MVC model in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

I'm working on NodeJS + Sequelize app. Right now I have all my logic in controllers but I've been told that it is the wrong way (Fat Stupid Ugly Controllers). Here is my controller file:

```
const Deals = require('../models').deals;

module.exports = {
  createDeal: (req, res, next) => {
    const { description, category, open_time, close_time, property_id } = req.body;
    return Deals
    .create({ description, category, open_time, close_time, property_id })
    .then(deal => res.status(200).json({ status: 'Created one property', deal }))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },

  getAllDeals: (req, res, next) => {
    return Deals
    .findAll({paranoid: false})
    .then(deals => res.status(200).json({ status: 'Retrieved all deals', deals }))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },

  getSingleDeal: (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    return Deals
    .findById(id)
    .then(deal => res.status(200).json({ status: 'Retrieved one deal', deal }))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },

  updateDeal: (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { description, category, open_time, close_time } = req.body;
    return Deals
    .findById(id)
    .then(deal => {
      if (!deal) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Deal not found' })
      }
      return deal
      .update({
        description: description,
        category: category,
        open_time: open_time,
        close_time: close_time
      })
      .then(deal => res.status(200).json({ status: 'Updated one deal', deal }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },

  destroyDeal: (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    return Deals
    .findById(id)
    .then(deal => {
      if (!deal) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Deal not found' })
      }
      return deal
      .destroy()
      .then(() =>  res.status(200).json({ status: 'Deleted one deal', deal }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    })
  }
}
```

Here is the model file that I have:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Deals = sequelize.define('deals', {
    description: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    category: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    open_time: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    close_time: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    property_id: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true
  });
  Deals.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Deals.belongsTo(models.properties, {
      foreignKey: 'property_id',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
  };
  return Deals;
};
```

So, I've been told that my updateDeal() method is wrong because it makes more than one request to the model or database, when it should be only "getting and analyzing request from the user and choosing the next step (like sending it to other elements of the system)". So, I'm supposed to bring all the logic from the controller to my models functions. I'd like to have somebody's explanation on how it works or some code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to change it. This is from my controller:

```
updateDeal: (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    return Deals
      .updateById(id, req.body)
      .then(deal => res.status(200).json({ status: 'Updated one deal', deal }))
      .catch(error => {
        return res.status(400).send({message: error.message})
      });
  }
```

This is from the model:

```
Deals.updateById = function(id, data){
    return Deals
      .findById(id)
      .then(deal => {
        if (!deal) {
          throw Error('Deal Not Found')
        }
        return deal
        .update(data, {fields: Object.keys(data)})
      })

  }
  return Deals;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define functions to get this data as either static or instance methods on your sequelize models and then access them in your routes via Model.method(). Very nice way to keep routes clean. You could also define the functions in another file and then assign them to the model.

i wrote a bunch of these to use for testing on my userdata model in an old student project here's an example:

```
"use strict";
const { Model, Op, Validator } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class UserData extends Model {
    async getNotes() {
      const Photo = sequelize.models.Photo;
      const TextNote = sequelize.models.TextNote;
      let objectTextNotes = {};
      let objectPhotos = {};

      const photos = await Photo.findAll({
        where: { authorId: this.id },
        order: [["createdAt"]],
      });

      const textNotes = await TextNote.findAll({
        where: { authorId: this.id },
        order: [["createdAt"]],
      });

      for (let photo of photos) {
        photo = photo.toJSON();
        objectPhotos[photo.id] = photo;
      }

      for (let textNote of textNotes) {
        textNote = textNote.toJSON();
        objectTextNotes[textNote.id] = textNote;
      }

      return { photos: objectPhotos, textNotes: objectTextNotes };
    }
    // query notebook model for any notebooks and any image notebooks that belong to the user and return them as arrays inside
    // a composite object

    // getpals gets any of the pal relationships of the user. the user could be found as palOne or palTwo
    async getPals() {
      const Pal = sequelize.models.Pal;
      const objectPals = {};
      const pals = await Pal.findAll({
        where: {
          [Op.or]: [{ palOne: this.id }, { palTwo: this.id }],
        },
        include: { model: sequelize.models.UserData },
      });

      for (let pal of pals) {
        pal = pal.toJSON();
        pal.palOne === this.id
          ? (objectPals[pal.palTwo] = pal.palTwo)
          : (objectPals[pal.palOne] = pal.palOne);
      }
      return objectPals;
    }

    // extract the pals from the object returned by getPals;
    async getPalsByIds(idObj) {
      const User = sequelize.models.User;
      const ids = Object.values(idObj);
      const palsObject = {};
      const users = await User.findAll({
        where: {
          id: ids,
        },
      });
      for (let user of users) {
        user = user.toJSON();
        palsObject[user.id] = user;
      }
      return { pals: palsObject };
    }

    // query for and return any collaborations that the user exists in under the key collaboratorId
    async getCollaborations() {
      const Collaboration = sequelize.models.Collaboration;
      const objectCollaborations = {};
      const collaborations = await Collaboration.findAll({
        where: { collaboratorId: this.id },
        order: [["createdAt"]],
      });
      for (let collaboration of collaborations) {
        collaboration = collaboration.toJSON();
        objectCollaborations[collaboration.id] = collaboration;
      }

      return objectCollaborations;
    }

    // query for and return any posts that the user exists in under the key authorIdId
    async getPosts() {
      const Post = sequelize.models.Post;
      const objectPosts = {};

      const posts = await Post.findAll({
        where: { authorId: this.id },
        order: [["createdAt"]],
      });

      for (let post of posts) {
        post = post.toJSON();
        objectPosts[post.id] = post;
      }
      return posts;
    }
    // query for and return any comments the user has left on a post the user exists in under the key userId
    async getComments() {
      const Comment = sequelize.models.Comment;
      const objectComments = {};

      const comments = await Comment.findAll({
        where: { userId: this.id },
        order: [["createdAt"]],
      });

      for (let comment of comments) {
        comment = comment.toJSON();
        objectComments[comment.id] = comment;
      }
      return objectComments;
    }

    // query for and return any reactions the user has left on a post the user exists in under the key userId
    async getReactions() {
      const Reaction = sequelize.models.Reaction;
      const reactions = await Reaction.findAll({
        where: { userId: this.id },
        order: [["createdAt"]],
      });
      return reactions;
    }
    static async createDefaultCollection(userId) {
      const Collection = sequelize.models.Collection;
      const collection = await Collection.create({
        name: "Misc",
        authorId: userId,
        isPublic: false
      });
      const user = await this.findByPk(userId);
      await user.update({ defaultCollection: collection.id });
    }

    static async createDefaultAlbum(userId) {
      const PhotoAlbum = sequelize.models.PhotoAlbum;
      const album = await PhotoAlbum.create({
        name: "Default Photo Album",
        authorId: userId,
        isPublic: false
      });
      const user = await this.findByPk(userId);
      await user.update({ defaultAlbum: album.id });
    }

    static associate(models) {
      UserData.belongsTo(models.UserData, { foreignKey: "id" });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Collection, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Notebook, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.PhotoAlbum, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.TextNote, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Photo, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Reaction, {
        foreignKey: "userId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Reaction, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Comment, {
        foreignKey: "userId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Comment, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Collaboration, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Collaboration, {
        foreignKey: "collaboratorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Post, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Audio, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Link, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.AudioAlbum, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.PostContent, {
        foreignKey: "authorId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Pal, {
        foreignKey: "palOne",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.hasMany(models.Pal, {
        foreignKey: "palTwo",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        hooks: true,
      });

      UserData.belongsToMany(models.UserData, {
        as: "palOne",
        foreignKey: "palOne",
        through: models.Pal,
        otherKey: "palTwo",
      });

      UserData.belongsToMany(models.UserData, {
        as: "palTwo",
        foreignKey: "palTwo",
        through: models.Pal,
        otherKey: "palOne",
      });
    }
  }
  UserData.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
          model: "User",
          key: "id",
        },
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          len: [4, 30],
          isNotEmail(value) {
            if (Validator.isEmail(value)) {
              throw new Error("Cannot be an email.");
            }
          },
        },
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          len: [3, 256],
          isEmail: true,
        },
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      defaultCollection: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      defaultAlbum: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      avatarUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      bgImgUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      bgColor: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      palsOnly: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "UserData",
      defaultScope: {
        attributes: {
          exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt"],
        },
      },
    }
  );
  return UserData;
};
```